# jQuery validation plugin - focus event inconsistent on key/mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using the query validation plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) and my goal is to show error messages before the form is submitted. To do this I'm using the `.valid()` method.

I don't want to show these messages until there's an error, so I'm hiding them first. When the field is focused the first time, I don't want to show an error message. This works great when focusing the input with the mouse, however when you use the tab key to focus the field the error message is shown anyway.

I've created a fiddle here to demonstrate the focus problem: http://jsfiddle.net/tucsonlabs/WQnHN/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use a combination of the code from @mindandmedia and @Fabian.

Here's what worked for me:

```
var code; 

$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 9) {
        return false;
    }
});

$('#myForm').validate();

$('input').blur(function() {
    if( !$(this).valid() ) { 
         $(this).next('label.error').show();                
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/yQRvZ/

```
var code;
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 9) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Everytime you release a key (this is `.keyup()`) and an `input` field is focused this jQuery code checks for the keycode of the released key.
For `Tab` the keycode is `9`, so everytime you release Tab, `return false;` prevents the default event and prevents the event from bubbling up.

Comment: thank you, somebody will read this in the future and thank you as well

Answer (score 1):

This works better:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').validate();

    //$('#myForm').valid();
    $('#myForm').hideErrors();

    $('input').blur(function() {
        if( !$(this).valid() ) $(this).next('label.error').show();                
    });
});​
```

Comment: This helped a lot. There isn't a .hideErrors() method, so I wrote one. It turned out that I didn't need to use it at all though.

Comment: glad i could help. hideErrors in jquery: `$('label.error').hide();`

Comment: Yeah, I did something along those lines.