# jquery validation initiation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This is really basic I know, but I'm trying to get a form element to validate onblur or while typing.  I'm having a really difficult time getting the thing to function right.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({
       rules: {
                a: {
                    onkeyup:true,
                    required:true,
                    minlength:2
                   }
        },      
        messages: {
                a: {
                    required: "enter your name!"
                   }       
        }  

    }); 
 });
```

I can get the thing to partially work...but I have to click in and out of the input after entering something.  Why is this?  I then added this

```
    $('#a').blur(function(){
        $("form").validate().element("#a");
    });
```

it works onblur but when I go back and enter a valid entry, the error message doesn't go away.  Here is the html:

```
<div>
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
</form>
</div>
```

Here are the fiddles:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmw562/S7AKK/16/

http://jsfiddle.net/mmw562/S7AKK/17/

Can someone explain what is going on?  I sure appreciate your help even though I know this is pretty basic stuff....

Comment: ok, I got rid of the onkeyup and that seemed to make all the difference...not sure why that was fowling things up

Comment: That's because onkeyup is not a validation rule!  It's a .validate() option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), `onkeyup:` is a `.validate()` option and not a field validation rule.   You must place it accordingly...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('form').validate({

    // "onkeyup" is the default behavior, leave it out unless disabling
    // onkeyup: false,  

       rules: {
            a: {
                required:true,
                minlength:2
            }
        },      
        messages: {
            a: {
                required: "enter your name!"
            }       
        }  

    }); 
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

`onkeyup:` is the default behavior, so simply leave it out for the default behavior.  Setting it to `true` is not only redundant, it actually breaks its intended functionality.

If you need to disable it, set it to `false`:

```
onkeyup: false
```

If you need to change the default behavior of `onkeyup`, use the function:

```
onkeyup: function(element, event) {
   // your custom onkeyup functionality
}
```

And purely for reference, this is how the default `onkeyup:` function operates:

```
onkeyup: function(element, event) {
    if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === '' ) {
        return;
    } else if ( element.name in this.submitted || element === this.lastActive ) {
        this.element(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default behaviour of onkeyup is truthy.  There is no need to set it to true, indeed if you do this you get a script error.  See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938431/jquery-plugin-validate-revalidate-as-typing-mouse-focus/13519912#13519912

Comment: @politus, Indeed I now remember this and updated my answer accordingly.  However, you will not get a script error.  Setting `onkeyup: true` is effectively the same as setting it `false`; it just disables `onkeyup`.  (At least in the latest version.)